# How can I know how many parameters a method passes to a block?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9

If I have two variables like `a` and `h`.

```
a = ["cat", "dog", "mat"]
h = {cat: 'gatto', dog: 'cane', mat: 'stuoia'}   # (Italian translations)
```

And I call the method `.each` on them, if I don't know the kind of object they are pointing to, how can I know that the block passed to `a.each` can take **one** parameter and the block passed to `b.each` can take **two**?

In other words, when I pass a block to a method, how can I know how many block parameters the method will set?

Is there `some_method` which returns the number of parameters a block should take? So that `obj.general_method_that_takes_a_block.some_method` would return the number of parameters that `general_method_that_takes_a_block` passes to its block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A straightforward way is:

```
a.each{|e| p [*e].length}
# => 1 1 1
h.each{|e| p [*e].length}
# => 2 2 2
```

Comment: What happens when `a = [ [1,2], [3,4] ]`?

Comment: @muistooshort In that case, it gives `2`. Note that the question is not asking whether the receiver is a hash or an array. Inside the `each` block, the case you mention cannot be distinguished from a hash.

Comment: Interesting, can you explain how it works? What the `*` operator does in that circumstance?

Comment: You answer is the better so far. Another approach, especially when knowing the number of parameters isn't enough without knowing also their kinds, could be `{ |*e| p e}`. For example in this case: `h.each_with_index{ |*e| p e}`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `each` blocks always gets a single parameter, it never gets two. In the Hash case, when you do this:

```
h.each { |k, v| ... }
```

Ruby is, more or less, doing this behind your back:

```
h.each { |a| k, v = a; ... }
```

So you could check if the block's argument is an Array:

```
e.each do |x|
    if x.kind_of? Array
        # e might be a Hash
    else
        # e might be an Array
    end
end
```

The problem is that `e` might be something like `[ [1,2], [3,4] ]` which would incorrectly put you into the *might be a Hash* branch; this sort of `e` will also fool a `[*e].length` check.

I don't think there is any clean and simple way to know what you're iterating over from inside the block.

Comment: The OP is not asking to distinguish a hash or an array. Once inside the `each` block, there is no difference between a hash and cases like `[[1, 2], [3, 4]]`. And if I were to use `kind_of?`, I would use it outside of the `each` block.

Comment: In my question `each` is just an example method, but I am actually referring to a general method, not only `each`. Just edited my question to made it clearer. Thank you.